# How to buffering fast of audio files in ios application?

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudioplayer, avplayer, buffering

I am trying to buffer a audio file  which i am trying to load from server URL.The audio file length is 3 to 4 minutes.Whenever i am using AvAudioPlayer or AvPlayer it is taking so much time to load the audio file.I have tried to implement third party code like DOUAudioStreamer and Matt Gallagher's one,but i did not get expected results.Please help me if you have any alternate solution.

Comment: I am loading my audio my file from server url and i cannot add sound files in my project,It will take so much storage.

Comment: You mean for testing purpose i just attached audio file in my project and convert those files into a binary format to play a file.

Comment: Man actually i am retrieving audio URL from iTunes API and sound cloud API and trying to play it and it is playing for 2 to 3 minutes.I just want to play audio files as soon as possible.

Comment: And yes my IPA size is 11 mb.

Comment: Yes i check my app on high speed(3G connection) but still it is taking time.Is there is any buffering method so that we can buffer my music file fast.